# Python - Improvinng speed of my algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, dictionary, optimization

I need to create a multi tiered dict in Python that ends up similar to this

```
    "objects": {
    "LOCATION 1": {
        "EMPLOYEE 1": {
            "19": 3,
            "20": 0,
            "21": 0,
            "40": 4
        },
        "EMPLOYEE 2": {
            "24": 0,
            "42": 11,
            "43": 13
        }
    },...
      ...
      ...
```

Its a dict that shows work hours logged by each employee per week by Location.

A typical record follows this format [LOCATION,EMPLOYEE,HOURS_LOGGED,DATE], For each record I am deriving the week number from the date.

My current algorithm which takes approx 10 secs to make this using 10,000 records is as follows

```
        result={}
        if (location in result):
            if (engineer in result[location]):
                if (week in result[location][engineer]):
                    result[location][engineer][week]=result[location][engineer][week]+laborminutes
                else:
                    result[location][engineer][week]=laborminutes
            else:
                result[location][engineer]={week:laborminutes}
        else:
            result[location]={engineer:{week:laborminutes}}
```

Anyway I can imrpove on this

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since SO is meant for users who have code that is not working, you will want to use the link Arnav provided and post this over on CodeReview. CR is dedicated to helping programmers improve the quality and efficiency of their code. You'll get an answer over there that will be far more likely to help you improve.

Comment: Thanks will try it out

Comment: The snippet above is off-topic on Code Review, though, since its missing several parts to get actually reviewed. Please [have a look at the help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before you post your code there.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Please have a look at https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users before you redirect users to CR.

Comment: @BrandonBarney A significant proportion of requests on SO specifically deal with improving performance. in fact, there is a performance tag on SO. do you have a meta reference for your stance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) offers one way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int)))
result[location][engineer][week] += laborminutes
```

`collections.defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`. We have defined a nested structure of `dict(dict(dict(int)))`. Since the defaultvalue for `int` is 0, we can easily increment values by `laborminutes` given arbitrary keys `location`, `engineer`, `week`.

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try

Comment: This seems to work, I will have to confirm that the data is correct